# Should we merge the "homophonic-kanji" and "kanji-choice" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I ran across this question today, currently tagged [kanji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kanji):

[Difference between the kanjis for "tears/なみだ": 涙 and 泪](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32747/difference-between-the-kanjis-for-tears-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%BF%E3%81%A0-%E6%B6%99-and-%E6%B3%AA)

I wanted to retag it [kanji-choice](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kanji-choice), but as I typed the word *kanji* the [homophonic-kanji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homophonic-kanji) tag popped up as another suggestion, and I couldn't figure out how to distinguish them.

Here are the tag wiki excerpts, describing how they're intended to be used:

- [kanji-choice](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kanji-choice) (19 questions)

  > Questions in the japanese language that are related to choosing the right Kanji [sic]
- [homophonic-kanji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homophonic-kanji) (72 questions)

  > 異字同音・異字同訓. Questions concerned with the fact that many kanji (漢字) may share a reading or pronunciation.

Right now, I'm not sure how to choose between them when tagging.  It seems like they're both basically about the same thing – the difference between multiple ways to write words that either *are* the same or *sound* the same with different kanji.

Should we merge these tags?  Or is there a reason to keep them separate?  If so, how do I distinguish between them when tagging?

Answer (score 2):

there is a [question about the choice between ~代 and ~費](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32675/542) that would be tagged with [kanji-choice](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kanji-choice) but not with [homophonic-kanji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homophonic-kanji). But I suppose we could just as well tag it with [word-choice](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice)

Comment: Someone might also tag that question with [nuances].

Comment: It does seem, though, like the question isn't actually about choosing *kanji* per se, just about the difference between two words that happen to be written with different kanji.  So I think [tag:word-choice] makes more sense for that question.